# BLE automatically pairing with passkey

Tags: android, authentication, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to connect to BLE device automatically by using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38055699/programmatically-pairing-with-a-ble-device-on-android-4-4) answer.

I've successfully set up `BroadcastReceiver` for `BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST` action and looks it works ok with `PIN` pairing, but in case of `passkey` app receive `BluetoothDevice.PAIRING_VARIANT_PASSKEY` error, and `device.setPin()` have no effect. and as I can see in `android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice` `setPasskey()` is not accessible:

```
/** @hide */
public boolean setPasskey(int passkey) {
    //TODO(BT)
    /*
    try {
        return sService.setPasskey(this, true, 4, passkey);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {Log.e(TAG, "", e);}*/
    return false;
}
```

so, it there any possibility to connect with `passkey` automatically?