# How to perform Secure BLuetooth Pairing in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, pairing

I have tried it with the following link but it does not ask for Pairing, it directly connects with the device.

[Programmatically pairing with a BLE device on Android 4.4+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38055699/programmatically-pairing-with-a-ble-device-on-android-4-4)

Please suggest something?

Comment: If your BLE device requires pairing to be used your phone should automatically show the pairing dialog

Comment: What is your scenario? Calling `createBond` on the `BluetoothDevice` object is what you should do. What exactly are you referring to when you say "secure"?